# run the first div onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list of div on a parent function, each does a onclick function.

How can I make a function that I can have a function to get the first div and run the onclick function?

The important thing is, my divs can be sorted. So after being sorted, the "first div" might not be the first anymore, so I need a function to be defined and each time when window is ready I run it once, and after the divs are sorted I run it again.

Thanks!

**Edit**: OK, say here's my code, I will sort those divs based on the id:

```
<div id="e">
<div id="e1" onclick="$(this).siblings().removeClass('someclass').addClass('someclass')">Something</div>
    <div id="e2" onclick="$(this).siblings().removeClass('someclass').addClass('someclass')">Something</div>
    <div id="e3" onclick="$(this).siblings().removeClass('someclass').addClass('someclass')">Something</div>
    <div id="e4" onclick="$(this).siblings().removeClass('someclass').addClass('someclass')">Something</div>
    <div id="e5" onclick="$(this).siblings().removeClass('someclass').addClass('someclass')">Something</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide some code so we can help you better.

Comment: Why are you using the inline event listeners? Why not add a class to all those divs and attach the event listener in your JavaScript, because you seem to be doing the same thing for all of them. Also, in your case it's easy to find and keep track of the first div, it's the div with the id `e1` (i.e. `var $firstDiv = $('#e1');`

Comment: by sorting, I mean I will sort from least to largest and also the opposite. so id e5 might be the first/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use delegate with `first` selector.

```
$("divsContainer").delegate("div:first", 'click', function(){

});
```

Note: Specify the appropriate selector for `divsContainer` which is actually the contianer in which all these divs are present.

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery to select all the divs on the page (or within any container containting these sortable divs). This will give you an array. Take the first element, and it will be first div.

Answer (score 0):

do you mean something  like this ?

```
$('#idOfParentDiv div:first').click();
```

Comment: that would get the first div in the page, that could be anything if there is more content

Comment: yes, but given the lack of any code I didn't put any other selector in there. I would have thought it fairly obvious that the selector should be narrowed down :) I've edited my answer to make it obvious

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#parent div:first-child').click();
```